# Concatenate string with ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its being annoying

**Following code :**

```
var arrays = [1,2,3];
alert('Array has ' + (arrays.length > 0) ? 'multiple':'single' + ' value');
```

alerts as the `multiple` where string is **not concatenated** with the ternary result.

**But this code :**

```
var arrays = [1,2,3];
alert('Array has ' + ((arrays.length > 0) ? 'multiple':'single') + ' value');
```

alerts as the `Array has multiple value` where string is concatenated with the ternary result.

**My question is :**

1. Why the first code is not concatenated with string.
2. Is there any syntax error in first code, if so why it doesnt throw an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first example is parsed this way

```
alert(('Array has ' + (arrays.length > 0)) ? 'multiple':('single' + ' value'));
```

given the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of `+` is much higher than that of `?:`.

Comment: Really so awesome answer.

Answer (score 5):

Both snippets are syntactically correct, but they differ because of operator precedence. The ternary operator has lower precedence than `+`.

In the first snippet:

```
var arrays = [1,2,3];
alert('Array has ' + (arrays.length > 0) ? 'multiple':'single' + ' value');
```

Javascript evaluates the first part `'Array has ' + (arrays.length > 0)`, which  gives the string `'Array has true'`. For conditional purposes, the nonempty string is the same as `true` (usually called a *truthy* value). Because the first operand in the ternary operator is truthy, the value of the whole expression will be the value of the expression `'multiple'`, that's between the `?` and the `:`.

When you add the parameters in the second snippet, you make the ternary operator take only `(arrays.length > 0)` as its condition. That's why the code works as expected.