# Unable to correctly write ternary operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine

I have an undefined variable and I check it in a string concat:

```
var undefinedVariable = undefined;
console.log("foo" + undefinedVariable === undefined ? "bar" : undefinedVariable.toString() );
```

Considering that undefinedVariable is undefined, `undefinedVariable.toString()` is an unreachable code. However, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined(…)

The strange thing is if I remove "foo" at the start of console.log, then the code works fine.

```
console.log(undefinedVariable === undefined ? "bar" : undefinedVariable.toString() );
```

I have tested in chrome and firefox and I get the same result so probably it is not a bug. Is there any explanation why JS engines try to run the unreachable part?

Comment: ^ The title is poorly worded for that question but if you read the accepted answer, it will explain this behavior.

Comment: @MikeC Nopes... Not a dupe of that / Wrong dupe target. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Like I said, it's not an exact dupe but the bug is the same. Ternary conditions are evaluated *after* concatenation which means that `undefinedVariable.toString()` is executed regardless of if `undefinedVariable === undefined`.

Comment: order of operations

Comment: @MikeC Got it now man, thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikeC, thank you for the help. The issue in your suggested dupe has the same solution. But, I do not think we can consider it as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate string with ternary operator in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444009/concatenate-string-with-ternary-operator-in-javascript) - the question is also being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325854/using-duplicate-report-to-increase-the-answer-votes-what-should-we-do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The `+` (concatenation operator) has a greater precedence than the `?:` (ternary operator). So, you need to enclose the ternary condition inside `()` because, it takes it along with the `+` (concatenation operator) and no more the left side is `undefined`. Use:

```
console.log("foo" + (undefinedVariable === undefined ? "bar" : undefinedVariable.toString()) );
```

You need to tell the JavaScript engine to evaluate the `undefinedVariable` separately and don't join both the `"foo"` and `undefinedVariable` and evaluate.

```js
var undefinedVariable = undefined;
console.log("foo" + (undefinedVariable === undefined ? "bar" : undefinedVariable.toString()) );
```

The above gives me: `foobar`.

[image: Output]

Comment: To note - this is because of operator operator precedence - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @SergeS Thanks, but how does that come into play here. Will `?` or `===` be considered as operator or what?

Comment: @PraveenKumar If you read that resource you'll see that `+` has higher precedence than `?:` which in this case means that concatenation takes place before the ternary condition is evaluated.

Comment: @MikeC He he... Sorry. `:P` So `?:` is also an operator. Thanks.

Comment: I will add that as a reason and correct my answer now.

Comment: @MikeC Check the updated answer. Now does it make sense?

Comment: @SergeS Check the updated answer. Now does it make sense? Thanks for the link and clarification buddy. `:)`